# Azure application - Set application permisions on behave of a user

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-application-settings

I am trying to find a way to allow an Admin account, that has proper permissions, to authorize (large amount of) users in our Azure AD. We *could* authorize users with a link and let them sign in, but that would be very time consuming, for we have many permissions that need to be granted from an admin account. This would mean we either need to sing in on every account, first with employees account and then with admin account.
All ideas would be helpful, thanks.
We are sadly only using a "free" version of Azure AD that comes with Microsoft 365 Business Standard licence.
[This is what we have added as permissions, they have admin consent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMyHZ.png)

Comment: Your Azure AD admin can consent for the entire organization so that individual users need not to. Have you tried that?

Comment: I have tried granting these permisions with an admin account, but it still gives me an Forbidden error. I have added a link with a picture above with permisions set by admin. I have also tried granting admin rights here: imgur.com/a/uC0OuZf

Comment: We fixed the problem, we had wrong owner in teams and it did not let us post. thank you anyway.